# Объединение словарей со вложенностями

Tags: python, словари, dict

Имею 2 словаря с вложениями одинаковой глубины вложенности,

```
dict = [{'ABC': {'ever': 25, 'sis': 0.01}}, {'ABC': {'ever': 75, 'sis': 0.02}}]
dict1 = [{'ABC': {'ever': 25, 'te': 72}}, {'ABC': {'ever': 25, 'te': 74}}]
```

Просьба, подсказать, как можно универсально объединить их для получений следующего формата:

```
merge_dict = [{'ABC': {'ever': 25, 'sis': 0.01, 'te': 72}}, {'ABC': {'ever': 75, 'sis': 0.02, 'te': 74}}]
```

Спасибо!

Comment: переименуйте первый словарь для начала. иначе его название совпадает с зарезервированным инициатором объекта языка python. и вопрос - количество ключей и сами ключи в обои словарях одинаковы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вероятно, можно проще, и не совсем универсально получилось, но вот так вроде работает (нужен Python >= 3.5):

```
dict1 = [{'ABC': {'ever': 25, 'sis': 0.01}}, {'ABC': {'ever': 75, 'sis': 0.02}}]
dict2 = [{'ABC': {'ever': 25, 'te': 72}}, {'ABC': {'ever': 25, 'te': 74}}]

merge_dict = [{k: {**d1[k], **d2[k]}} for d1,d2 in zip(dict1, dict2) for k in d1]
print(merge_dict)
```

Вывод:

```
[{'ABC': {'ever': 25, 'sis': 0.01, 'te': 72}}, {'ABC': {'ever': 25, 'sis': 0.02, 'te': 74}}]
```